# How to render a component by looping through the array in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i want to render a component if some condition is true and loop through that prop array.

Below is what i want to do

```
render() {
    return (
           {first_condition &&
               <div>some text</div>}
           {this.props.some_vars && 
               this.props.some_vars.forEach((var, index) => {
                   this.box_ref.current && var.name &&
                       <ChildComponent
                           element1={var.element1}
                           element2={var.element2}
                       />
           }//error here
       );
}
```

But the code gives me an error at the curly bracket...how should i render this childcomponent based on that condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There were bracket-related syntax errors.
- You'll have to use `map`, not `forEach`.
- `var` is a reserved keyword; use `variable`.
- To return multiple sibling components in `render`, wrap them in a fragment (`<></>`).
- You should also figure out a `key` for each component rendered in the loop.

```js
function render() {
  return (
    <>
      {first_condition && <div>some text</div>}
      {this.props.some_vars &&
        this.props.some_vars.map(
          (variable, index) =>
            this.box_ref.current &&
            variable.name && (
              <ChildComponent
                element1={variable.element1}
                element2={variable.element2}
              />
            )
        )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is this    <> doing after return statement. new to react. so thanks

Comment: As I said, it's a React fragment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`#Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`#Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which returns void.

Moreover:

1. You must [render a single React Node.](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)
2. [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is a preserved keyword.
3. You need to provide [`key` property](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in React Node's array.

```
// </> is sugar syntax for <React.Fragment/>
<>
  {first_condition && <div>some text</div>}
  {this.props.some_vars &&
    this.props.some_vars.map(
      (value, index) =>
        this.box_ref.current &&
        value.name && (
          <ChildComponent key={index} element1={value.element1} element2={value.element2} />
        )
    )}
</>
```

Refer to [`List and Keys` in React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should user `.map` (which is an array method in JS). *This returns a new array always.* It also returns *immutable* things, which are new and different from reference, it means if you change the provided array it will make no effect to the result of mapped array. *As ForEach loop is mutable*, this carry forward the reference.

That's why we use immutable like **.map**

Here, how we can use ?

```
        {this.props.some_vars.map(item, index) => 
            <ChildComponent
              key= {index}  //if you not pass the key it will throw warning.
              element1={item.element1}
              element2={item.element2}
            />
        }
```